# How could I get payments via google pay

Tags: javascript, react-native, payment-gateway, google-pay

I need a payment solution for my chatting app. Since I checked all the documentation of the google there is no sign solves my problem.

As I understand google only doing tokenization for credit cards. I think I need A payment gateway for that. But I couldn't understand what is DIRECT means.

However, on google, as I can see where you can create products in console, so why should I put products and prices in code lines?

What is difference between the gateway and direct?

Thanx for all!

Answer (score 0):

Google Pay does not process payments. You need to either refer to one of the [supported payment gateways](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/) in the configuration, or go for `DIRECT` if you are processing payments yourself on your own servers.